# Sitecore SXA export failing with error - startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: sxa, creative-exchange

I don't think this is self signed certificate issue I have alreacy set `name="XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.SkipServerCertificateValidation" value="true"`

Here is the stack trace of error from logs

---

```
startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Export.PageProcessing.StorePage.BuildItemPath(PageProcessingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Export.PageProcessing.StorePage.Process(PageProcessingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object ) 
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Export.Export.PageEnumeration.ProcessPage(ExportedPage exportedPage, ExportArgs args)  
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`1 action)   
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)  
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)  
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Jobs.Export.ExportBackgroundJob.Run(GetExportContextArgs args)
```

---

Comment: Possible reasons for your export to fail may be because the pages could not be rendered due to errors and/or linked assets are missing.